# nopcommerce paypal sandbox account not working

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, nopcommerce

I am testing paypal sandbox on nopcommerce. I have created  buyer(personal) and seller(business) accounts in paypal sandbox accounts. below is the business profile api credentials tab

```
 Classic TEST API credentials
```

Username:
kokxxx-facilitator_api1.gmail.com
Password:1392740961
Signature:
AeM4pXm0nQ-QLw4cuGtd3QQ4pDODA4SRJcPPOAjzkizlkWnhbaXdAgen

I have configured paypal payment method   I used business email kokoxxx-facilitator@gmail.com   Notice it is different from username shown above
for pdt  I copied and pasted the signature show above
I left ipn handler blank.  Then I tested a transaction as guest and entered shipping and billing address  ( my actual texas address!) here i don't know if this matters. in payment method I see two options  credit card  and  yes credit card!! I proceed to enter the buyertest email as in sandbox account and entered my real credit card information.. and confrim.. it says success. but when I check sandbox account there is no mention of this transaction..also no notifications....can some one please guide me step by step how to make this work. I have paypal account and sandbox account had worked for me on sharepoint public website before.

Answer (score 0):

**CONFIGURATION FOR PAYPAL STANDARD IN NOPCOMMERCE**

If you're using this gateway ensure that your primary store currency is supported by Paypal.

To use PDT, you must activate PDT and Auto Return in your PayPal account profile. You must also acquire a PDT identity token, which is used in all PDT communication you send to PayPal. Follow these steps to configure your account for PDT:

1. Log in to your PayPal account.
2. Click the Profile subtab.
3. Click Website Payment Preferences in the Seller Preferences column.
4. Under Auto Return for Website Payments, click the On radio button.
5. For the Return URL, enter the URL on your site that will receive the transaction ID posted by PayPal after a customer payment (http://www.yourStore.com/Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/PDTHandler).
6. Under Payment Data Transfer, click the On radio button.
7. Click Save.
8. Click Website Payment Preferences in the Seller Preferences column.
9. Scroll down to the Payment Data Transfer section of the page to view your PDT identity token.

Two ways to be able to receive IPN messages (optional):

The first way is to check 'Enable IPN' below. It will include in the request the url of you IPN handler

The second way is to confugure your paypal account to activate this service; follow these steps:
1. Log in to your Premier or Business account.
2. Click the Profile subtab.
3. Click Instant Payment Notification in the Selling Preferences column.
4. Click the 'Edit IPN Settings' button to update your settings.
5. Select 'Receive IPN messages' (Enabled) and enter the URL of your IPN handler (http://www.yourStore.com/Plugins/PaymentPayPalStandard/IPNHandler).
6. Click Save, and you should get a message that you have successfully activated IPN.

---

**NOTES**

- Your PDT Token is not the same as your paypal signature.
- To use **paypal standard** you need to use your **PDT Identity Token**.
- The PDT Token is **59** characters long.
- The PDT page can be found under **profile/my account settings/Website Payment Preferences**:
  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-website-payments
- When doing a test transaction. Log into paypal with your **buyers** sandbox account.
- Paypal e-mail notification can be found under **profile/my account settings/Instant Payment Notification (IPN)**:
  https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_profile-ipn-notify
- Nopcommerce email account must first be setup from **configuration/email accounts** and ensure a test email send successfully.
- Nopcommerce e-mail notification can be setup from **content management/message templates**.